# Strange this-> behaviour

Tags: c++, class, memory, this

So i have the following class

> ```
> class Community
> {
> private:
>   char* Name;
>   char foundationDate[11];
>   Person* founder;
>   int maxMembersCount;
>   int membersCount;
>   Person* members;
>   static int communitiesCount;
> ```
>
> .....

and i want to implement a copy constructor :

```
Community::Community(const Community& other)
{
    this->Name = new char[strlen(other.Name)+1];
    strcpy(this->Name,other.Name);
    strcpy(this->foundationDate,other.foundationDate);
    this->founder = other.founder;
    this->maxMembersCount = other.maxMembersCount;
    this->membersCount = other.membersCount;
    this->members = new Person[this->maxMembersCount];
    this->members = other.members;
    communitiesCount++;
}
```

but this code crashes whenever i say Community A=B;
so for me this code seems legit, but when i start debugging there is the message: this-> "unable to read memory". Please help me if you need more code example please let me know.

---

```
Community::Community(const char* name , char foundDate[],Person* founder,int maxMembers) {

    this->Name = new char[strlen(name)+1];
    strcpy(this->Name,name);
    strcpy(this->foundationDate,foundDate);
    this->founder = new Person(founder->getName(),founder->getEGN(),founder->getAddress());
    this->maxMembersCount = maxMembers;
    this->membersCount = 2;
    this->members = new Person[this->maxMembersCount];
    communitiesCount++;
```

}

this is the main constructor of the class which works just fine....

Comment: Are you sure that `Name` and `foundationDate` are `null` terminated or properly initialized? Also, you are assigning new memory to `this->memebers` and then overwriting the pointer right after, although I don't think that causes the problem you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check that `other.Name` is filled with a pointer to a null-terminated string, that `other.foundationDate` contains a null-terminated string. That is, you pass good pointers to `strlen` and `strcpy`.

If that's true, check that `B` in the assignment is accessible altogether.

If that's true too, `printf` everything. And debug where exactly the exception occurs. Or post whole code that is compilable and which reproduces the error.

Also note that here:

```
this->members = new Person[this->maxMembersCount];
this->members = other.members;
```

the first assignment does nothing (leaks memory, in fact) while the second double deletes your memory upon object destruction (if you properly `delete[] members`).

Comment: I think your sentences about the `members` member are incorrect, did you edit them incorrectly?

Comment: no everything except the copy constructor and operator= works just perfect. It crashes even if i only say     this-> membersCount = other.membersCount ...

Comment: I did not edit it at all. The notice is correct, the second assignment renders the first useless. 
I'd like to see a smallest possible example to repeat your bug.

Comment: Problem solved... in this->members = other.members; my program tries to double delete the objects.. Thank you all for helping :)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems here, any of whichi could be part or all of the problem.

- If `Name` or `foundationDate` is not null-terminated on the right-hand side, it will run off and copy bad memory.
- If `founder` or `members` are owned by the object, you will either leak memory if you don't delete them in the destructor, or cause a whole variety of memory-related problems when you shallow-copy and then delete twice, etc.

To fix this, just make your `Name` and `foundationDate` `std::string`, and then make `founder` and `members` be owned by value rather than by pointer. If you absolutely have to allocate them on the heap use a smart pointer such as `shared_ptr` to hold it instead of a bug-prone raw pointer.